# Typescript primitive type

Tags: typescript

In typescript, is there a built-in "primitive" type or something like that?

I mean something sucn as `type primitive = 'number' | 'boolean' | 'string';`.

I know that I could create it myself, but it would just be cool.

Comment: what is the use case of this 'primitive' type?

Comment: Nope, I've never seen it, but it couldn't be hard to make yourself.

Comment: The usecase of this type should be obvious, if I know that a type will not be neither a function, nor an object/array, I can deem it as a primitive type. Something like 'number' | 'boolean' | 'string' (I don't know if I miss anything). It can be made with a simple type alias but it would have been beautiful if it was already defined. Same as an Omit<type> or a Pick<type> type, without making it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone already had thought about this and made an npm module that has this **primitive** type and many other utils. The module is [ts-essential](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#Install).